# How to make customer login required in magento module?

Tags: magento-1.7

I created a custom module in magento, and I need to make it work only for customers who are logged in. How should I make customer login required for a magento module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add this inside your frontend controller(s) of your module

```
public function preDispatch()
{
    parent::preDispatch();
    if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'));
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to **Marius**, the following worked for me (with the URL variant):

```
    public function preDispatch()
{
    parent::preDispatch();
    if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('customer/account/login');
        return;
    }
}
```